# How to stop scroll top on clicking next or prev btn of Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Following is the simple carousel in use, even it looks fine here in coding, however on browser whenever tried to click `next` or `prev` button, page is  `scrolled` to top of HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>SAMPLE CONTENT HERE</h1>
    <h1>SAMPLE CONTENT HERE</h1>
    <h1>SAMPLE CONTENT HERE</h1>
    <h1>SAMPLE CONTENT HERE</h1>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Found the reason somewhere with `data-target`, however, unable to figure it out, and how to stop scrolling top...

Looking for simplest solution to understand, as new to HTML..

Thanks in advance

Cheers..

Answer (score 11):

Just change `href="#myCarousel"` to `data-target="#myCarousel"` .

Answer (score 0):

**Tip #1**:

You can add event.preventDefault() to prevent default behaviour with hashbang:

```
$('a[class^=carousel-control-]').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Tip #2**:

If you have plugins like SmoothScroll, you can unbind it by:

```
$('a[class^=carousel-control-]').unbind('click.SmoothScroll');
```

To look for all the click events bind to the element, use:

```
jQuery._data($('a[class^=carousel-control-]')[0], "events")
```